# pmd eclipse jdk compatibility

Tags: eclipse-plugin, pmd

I have installed version 3.2.6.v200903300643 of the PMD Plug-in for Eclipse (which is version 3.7.*).

When I try to run the  Generate Abstract Syntax Tree, I get the following error

PMD Exception : net.sourceforge.pmd.ast.ParseException: Can't use static imports when running in JDK 1.4 mode

My question is: How can I configure which JDK compatibility mode PMD is running in when used through Eclipse ?

I can't find any configuration options for this in the properties overview.

Regards
Esben

Answer (score 0):

Most probably you need to configure the `maven-pmd-plugin` to use the correct [targetJdk](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-pmd-plugin/pmd-mojo.html#targetJdk) option value. It does not explicitly say if this option defaults to `1.4`, but it seems so.